# Icon pack is not showing up in launchers

Tags: android, templates, icons, launcher

my icon pack is not showing up in the launchers. I, turned it into an iconpack template (so it has more information such as an about dev section, etc.) but is no longer showing up in the launchers. any suggestions? Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.slpcatalyst.flushlens"
android:versionCode="1" 
android:versionName="1" > <!-- android:versionCode="1" +1 with every update! android:versionName="1" Whatever you      like-->

<!-- Wallpaper --> 


<!-- Screen -->
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true"  android:xlargeScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" /> 


<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" /> 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER">
</uses-permission>
<!-- Main Activity -->
<application
android:icon="@drawable/icon"
android:label="@string/theme_title" 
android:allowBackup="true" 
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"     
>

<activity
android:name="com.slpcatalyst.flushlens.MainActivity"
android:label="@string/theme_title"  >

<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
</intent-filter>
</activity>   

<!-- Other Activites -->          
<activity
android:name=".AboutDev"
/> 

<!-- ADW / Nova / Holo -->
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<action android:name="org.adw.launcher.THEMES" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>

<intent-filter>
<action android:name="org.adw.launcher.icons.ACTION_PICK_ICON" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>

<!-- Go / Nova -->
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<action android:name="com.gau.go.launcherex.theme" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>

<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.INFO" />
</intent-filter>

<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>

<!-- LauncherPro / Holo -->
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="com.fede.launcher.THEME_ICONPACK" />
</intent-filter>

<!-- Apex -->
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="com.anddoes.launcher.THEME" />
</intent-filter>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest's intent-filters are not part of any activity tag. Though launchers generally ignore the activity itself, it's still required as that is how the themes are queried by the system.

Include the intent-filter under the activity tag.

```
<activity android:name=".AboutDev" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <action android:name="com.gau.go.launcherex.theme" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```